# Perl - truncate where values overlap and concatenate

Tags: mysql, regex, perl, concatenation, truncate

I am new to the Perl language and am trying to convert some data from a MYSQL database.

I'm working on pulling addresses from two different tables, and my goal is to concatenate a "complete" address. In some cases the addresses are fragmented between columns from each table.

For example:

```
╔═══╦═════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║   ║ a.address_1         ║ b.address_2          ║
╠═══╬═════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 6418 Main St        ║ Main St, Detroit MI  ║
║ 2 ║ 11 S Pole Rd        ║ Miami, FL 33166      ║
║ 3 ║ Pittsburgh, PA 15222║ Third Ave, Pittsburgh║
╚═══╩═════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

I need to check to see if any part of the address is matching, and if so truncate the overlap and concatenate the remaining address

```
╔═══╦══════════════════════════════════════╗
║   ║ address                              ║
╠═══╬══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 6418 Main St, Detroit MI             ║
║ 2 ║ 11 S Pole Rd Miami, FL 33166         ║
║ 3 ║ Fifth Avenue, Pittsburgh, PA 15222   ║
╚═══╩══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

At this point I am pulling the two addresses in and storing them, but now I need to convert them to a single "complete" address.

Can someone please help me with a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you could start with is a regular expression that splits every word of the first data entry (`a.address_1`) into an array:

```perl
my ($addr_1, $addr_2) = $sth->fetchrow_array();
my @words = ($addr_1 =~ /(.*?)\s+/g);
```

After that you can iterate over every word and remove it from the second address

```perl
for my $word (@words) {
    $addr_2 =~ s/$word//g;
}
```

Once you're done with that you can basically merge the two strings into one:

```perl
my $concatenated_string = $addr_1 . $addr_2;
```

And after you've done that you should be very close to what you were asking.

NOTE: Syntax errors might be possible, I've written this off the top of my head.